# How to get the jQuery element (or attributes) in a click event in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the following code:

**HTML**:

```
<div id='example'>
 <a href='#' data-name='foo' class='example-link'>Click Me</a>
 <a href='#' data-name='bar' class='example-link'>Click Me</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
example_view = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#example"),
    events: {
      'click .example-link' : 'example_event'
    },
    example_event : function(event) {
      //need to get the data-name here
    } 
});
```

how can I get the `data-name` attribute of the link that was clicked inside of the `example_event` function ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this.

```
example_event : function(event) {
  //need to get the data-name here
  var name = $(event.target).data('name');
}
```

Answer (score 21):

You can also do this without jQuery using JavaScript's [getAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) method:

```
example_event : function(event) {
  //need to get the data-name here
  var name = event.target.getAttribute('data-name');
}
```

Comment: This worked for me using CoffeeScript, the accepted answer didn't.

Comment: either answer will work just fine if converted correctly to coffeescript